# Pentaho Kettle support for EhCache

Tags: ehcache, pentaho, kettle, ehcache-bigmemory

I am reading the data from one data source, transforming the data and storing the data in another database. The stored data in database I want to synchronize with EhCache. Is this possible to synchronize the data with EhCache ?

Any help is appreciated

thanks
Lokesh

Comment: Errm, ehcache is not a database it's, err a cache :)  It has an API for managing the cache, you could try that. There doesnt seem to be a jdbc driver for it - that would be the usual way.

Comment: if you cannot find either a jdbc driver or a step for it, you might try writing a custom java or javascript step for it